# Получить ключ по значению, если значения словаря - списки элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Eсть словарь, значения в нем - списки элементов:

```
d = {'Люди': ['Ваня', 'Маша', 'Петя'], 'Кони': ['Горбунок', 'Буцефал']}
```

Есть ли способ получить из словаря ключ, если известен один из элементов списка?

```
Ваня - Люди, Буцефал - Кони, Чубакка - None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это зависит от размеров словаря. Если речь идет о 10<sup>4</sup> элементах и меньше, то можно просто построить обратный словарь:

```
In [1]: d = {'Люди': ['Ваня', 'Маша', 'Петя'], 'Кони': ['Горбунок', 'Буцефал']}

In [2]: from collections import defaultdict

In [3]: d1 = defaultdict(list)

In [4]: for k, vs in d.items():
   ...:     for v in vs:
   ...:         d1[v].append(k)
   ...:         

In [5]: d1
Out[5]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'Буцефал': ['Кони'],
             'Ваня': ['Люди'],
             'Горбунок': ['Кони'],
             'Маша': ['Люди'],
             'Петя': ['Люди']})

In [6]: '; '.join(x + ' - ' + ', '.join(map(str, d1.get(x, [None]))) for x in ['Ваня', 'Буцефал', 'Чубакка'])
Out[6]: 'Ваня - Люди; Буцефал - Кони; Чубакка - None'
```

Если же количество элементов достаточно большое, имеет смысл задуматься о реализации двунаправленного словаря.

Answer (score 2):

Строим обратный словарь:

```
d = {'Люди': ['Ваня', 'Маша', 'Петя'], 'Кони': ['Горбунок', 'Буцефал']}
rev_d = dict((v, k) for k, vals in d.items() for v in vals)

# Проверяем
print(rev_d.get('Ваня'))
print(rev_d.get('Буцефал'))
print(rev_d.get('Чубакка')
```

Comment: Следует список использовать как в [ответе @soon](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513782/23044), если исходное значение может в нескольких списках встречаться (соответствовать нескольким ключам).

Comment: Да, если списки значений пересекаются, то следует использовать решение @soon.
Если нет, как в исходном запросе, то представленное чуть компактнее. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'Люди': ['Ваня', 'Маша', 'Петя', '1'], 'Кони': ['Горбунок', 'Буцефал', '1']}


def find_me(name):
    return [k for k in d if set(d[k]) & {name}]

print('Ваня :', find_me('Ваня'))
print('1 :', find_me('1'))
```

Вывод:

```
Ваня : ['Люди']
1 : ['Люди', 'Кони']
```

Comment: Не имеет смысла временный set создавать—`name in d[k]` работает как есть: `return [key for key, lst in d.items() if name in lst]`. Хотя если несколько имён хочется найти, то имеет смысл обратный словарь создать как в [ответе @soon](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513782/23044).